# Deprecated telecomManager.endCall() in android API 29 android

Tags: android, deprecated, phone-call, telecom-manager

Before I used below code to end the call

```
val telecomManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE) as TelecomManager
                if (PermissionsUtil(context).checkPermissions()) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                        telecomManager.endCall()
                    } else {
                        //telecomManager.isInCall
                        declinePhone(context)
                    }
                }
```

but now in API 29 telecomManager.endCall() shows deprecated.
Do I have to create a service running in the background CallScreeningService or InCallService?  where there is no direct method for endCall() third party apps cannot do this without becoming a default caller app.
If so then how I will get the call details and how to keep my service running in the background for Chinese rom

Comment: What is your question? [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager#endCall()) explain what you should use instead

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you have to create a CallScreeningService and users have to choose your app as an default app for Call Screening service....